Lumen/Lighthouse Custom @validator does not evaluate when the basic graphql validation passes
PHP : 8.3
Lumen : upgrade from 8 -> 10
Lighhouse : upgrade from 4.13 -> 5.72
The problem:
We are busy upgrading our systems, and I have a basic graphql validation on email.
input recipientRecordInput {
  memberId: Int @rename(attribute: "member_id")
  email: String! @rules(apply: ["required", "min:3", "max:200"])
}

I then have a more complex validation on email, being called as @validator:
extend type Mutation {
      sendMail(
        recipients: [recipientRecordInput!]!
        sentFrom: mailSenderInput! @rename(attribute: "sent_from")
        messageTemplate: MailMessageTemplateInput!
      ): [Mail]
        @validator

I know that no matter what happens, my class linked to @validator executes. It prints all the debug info I need. It sends back, upon failure, the following is the result of failing the more complex rule. This returned rule however gets ignored if the basic rule succeeded.
So if the basic rule, required, and min=3, max=200 is satisfied, it runs the complex rule but ignores the resultset, which is in itself a rule that says fail the attempt.
    return [
        $graphQlFieldIdentifier . 'recipients.*.email' => [
            function ($attribute, $value, $fail) { // @codingStandardsIgnoreLine
                $fail('Invalid copy type email address(es) provided. Email address(es) must end with @' . MailConstants::COMPANY_DOMAIN . '.'); // @codingStandardsIgnoreLine
            }
        ]
    ];

The problem is that when my basic validation rules succeed, The complex rule is executed, but the return I posted above is not executed. Basically the @validator runs the code and returns the rule, which says "fail the emails", but the resultset is being ignored.
Question 1: How can I let my custom complex rule execute completely, with its result set being validated along with my basic rule?
Question 2: I did not write this code above, so I cannot say why it was done like this, but should I rather rework this as an exception? I may be missing something that changed between Lighthouse versions.
